# Linking with sourcemaps in ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am having a problem with source maps or something similar.

When I put `console.log(...)` in the code, I see the message in console, but it links to compiled javascript, instead to source typescript file.

Am I missed something?
I am using blank project in ionic, e.g.:

`ionic start MyProjectName blank --type=ionic-angular`

Answer (score 0):

What helped me solving my sourcemap issues was, using --source-map flag for ionic serve and adding

```
"config": {
    "ionic_sass": "./sass.config.js"
 },
```

to package.json in the root folder. The content of sass.config.js was:

```
module.exports = {
  sourceMap: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will gonna check this in the next few days.